# SQL Subquery between two tables, the max date to compare with another date

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

First

```
Order   Product     Date of order
4772    CF007115    2014-03-31 14:24:29.000
```

and the second

```
Product     Date of buy             Price 
CF007115    2014-03-18              111.398
CF007115    2014-03-27              103.121
CF007115    2014-05-08              0.061
CF007115    2014-07-21              0.062
CF007115    2015-01-22              0.065
CF007115    2015-05-29              0.068
```

I need the next result

```
Order   Product     Date of order           date of buy             Price
4772    CF007115    2014-03-31              2014-03-27              103,121
```

**The result must show the price most near to the order.**

I trying with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  dbo.OPSinValor.orden, dbo.OPSinValor.CodComponente, dbo.OPSinValor.Fecha_Declaracion, dbo.EntradasParaOP3.FechaIngStock, dbo.EntradasParaOP3.ppp
FROM  dbo.OPSinValor 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.EntradasParaOP3 ON dbo.OPSinValor.CodComponente = dbo.EntradasParaOP3.Articulo
WHERE     (dbo.OPSinValor.CodComponente = 'CF007115')
GROUP BY dbo.OPSinValor.orden, dbo.OPSinValor.CodComponente, dbo.OPSinValor.Fecha_Declaracion, dbo.EntradasParaOP3.FechaIngStock, 
                      dbo.EntradasParaOP3.ppp
HAVING      (dbo.OPSinValor.Fecha_Declaracion >= MAX(dbo.EntradasParaOP3.FechaIngStock))
```

This is the result

```
4772    CF007115    2014-03-31  2014-03-18  111,398
4772    CF007115    2014-03-31  2014-03-27  103,121
```

I try with subqueries but the result give me all the records of the second table

Answer (score 0):

I expect your first table to be your orders and the second (with more rows) your product table - just to have a name convention.

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM products p
    WHERE p.[date of buy] <= o.[date of order]
    ORDER BY p[date of buy] DESC LIMIT 1
) as p
```